# Crear datos aleatorios si estos no existen en mi arreglo php

Tags: php, array, php7

días o noches
tengo este detalle que la verdad no eh encontrado solucion tengo dos arreglo de datos uno son ingresos y otro son egresos donde las fechas de estos dos datos no son iguales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en php no soy bueno con esto de los arreglos pero lo que estoy queriendo hacer es. Si la fecha de egresos no existe en la fecha de ingresos entonces  a egresos se crea datos aleatorios

hasta ahora es todo lo que he avanzado

```
$response = json_decode(
  $this->webservice->funcion('GET', $this->getTechoF, $params)
);
foreach (
  $response->data->data->ingresos->desglosado as $key => $value
){
  foreach (
    $value->detalles->MXN as $key_detalles => $value_detalles
  ){
    $data[] = [
      'fecha' => $key_detalles,
      'cantidades' => $value_detalles
    ];
  }
}
foreach (
  $response->data->data->egresos->desglosado as $key => $value
){
  foreach (
    $value->detalles->USD as $key_detalles => $value_detalles
  ){
    $data_egresos[] = [
      'fecha' => $key_detalles,
      'original' => $value_detalles->original,
      'tasa' => $value_detalles->tasa,
      'convertido' => $value_detalles->convertido
    ];
  }
}
foreach ( $data_egresos as $key_datos ) {
  foreach ( $data as $key_data_ingresos ) {
    if (
      $key_datos['fecha'] == $key_data_ingresos['fecha']
    ){
      $datos_nuevos_ingresos[] =$key_datos['fecha'];
    } else {
// ...
    }
  }
}
```

ejemplo:

```
Egresos: {
  "2022-10-01": {
    "original": 12981.29,
    "tasa": 20.19,
    "convertido": 262092.24510000003
  },
  "2022-10-02": {
    "original": 0,
    "tasa": 20.19,
    "convertido": 0
  },
  "2022-10-03": {
    "original": 139.96,
    "tasa": 20.19,
    "convertido": 2825.7924000000003
  },
  "2022-10-05": {
    "original": 0,
    "tasa": 0,
    "convertido": 0
  },
}


Ingresos:{
  "2022-10-01": 2036.96,
  "2022-10-02": 1305,
  "2022-10-03": 49755.81999999999,
  "2022-10-04": 123312,
}
```

En egresos la fecha `2022-10-04` no existe entonces  se crea pero el original, tasa y convertido solo tendran de valor el numero `0`

Comment: podrias colocar un ejemplo minimo de tu egresos e ingresos en formato texto y  cual deberia ser el resultado esperado?

Comment: claro en un momento lo hago

Comment: listo edite el comentario ya con un ejemplo